# How can I write blob datas to zip and download it in C#?

Tags: c#, file, zip, arrays, blob

Assume that I got some blobs from database.
Then I put them in Byte arrays. For example:

```
Byte[] lol1=(Byte[])reader["data1"];
Byte[] lol2=(Byte[])reader["data2"];
```

Now how can i write these byte arrays as file into zip and download it as file from browser in C#?

// Edit for clarity

Relevant codes in "Manager.cs" file like:

```
    public Byte[] FileDownload(string userName)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader = new MySqlCommand("SELECT veri FROM veriler WHERE kullanici_id = (SELECT id FROM uyeler WHERE kullanici_adi='" + userName + "')", con).ExecuteReader();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            GZipStream gzs = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress);
            while (reader.Read())
                gzs.Write((Byte[])reader["veri"], 0, ((Byte[])reader["veri"]).Length);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Relevant codes in "DataDown.aspx.cs" file like:

```
protected void download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.AddHeader("Content-type", ContentType);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Archive.zip");
    Response.BinaryWrite(new Manager().FileDownload(Session["user"].ToString()));
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

It returns a .zip file which is only file in it. It must be two files. Moreover, this one file is corrupted.

Comment: Did you try anything to do that?

Comment: Look at edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it cleanly, you'll need [System.IO.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) which is only available in .Net 4.5 forward.

```
string blobName = "data1";
string zipName = "database.zip";
Byte[] blob = (Byte[])reader[blobName];

using(MemoryStream zs = new MemoryStream())
{
  // Build the archive
  using(System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zs, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
  {
    System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry archiveEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(blobName);
    using(Stream entryStream = archiveEntry.Open())
    {
      entryStream.Write(blob, 0/* offset */, blob.Length);
    }
  }

  //Rewind the stream for reading to output.
  zs.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);

  // Write to output.
  Response.Clear();
  Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", zipName));
  Response.BinaryWrite(zs.ToArray());
  Response.End();
 }
```

If your data provider supports opening the blob as a stream, you can probably avoid reading the entry into a buffer, and instead use [`Stream.CopyTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx)

Comment: I used GZipStream class. System.IO.Compression has not ZipArchiveEntry class in my compiler. I'm using MS Visual Studio 2012. I guess its framework version is .Net 4.5. I edited my question. You can look. Thanks for answer.

Comment: It exists in .net 4.5. Just make sure that you included reference to System.IO.Compression.dll in your project. http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.aspx

Comment: I added it and your code is working for me. Thanks brother.