# Xamarin File.WriteAllBytes the method does not write data

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, writeallbytes

Here is my code:

```
string f = GetRefInfoServise.GetRefInfo("GA");
byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(f);

var backingFile = 
   Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "arch.zip");

File.WriteAllBytes(backingFile, data);`
```

The method does not return an exception, but the file is not written. I'm trying to do this on Android API 28

Comment: It seems that you want to add data to a zip file. You could check the similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140113/how-can-i-write-blob-datas-to-zip-and-download-it-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. I just didn't know about the internal storage. It is hidden from the user, so I couldn't find my file.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people :)